# Check if JavaScript input is empty

Tags: javascript, type-safety, polymorphism, typescript

Having a general utility function to see if the input is empty makes sense to me. Empty means different things depends on the type. I just spent ~5 minutes writing this one up, so I'm sure it's missing edge cases, and maybe I'm approaching the whole problem incorrectly.

#### Function

```
function isEmpty(input: any) {
    switch (typeof input) {
        case 'string':
            return input.length === 0;
        case 'object':
            return (input instanceof Array)? input.length === 0: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(input).length === 0;
        case 'number':
        default:
            return input === undefined;
    }
}
```

#### Basic [SONA!] testing

```
let s = '';
let o = {};
let n: number;
let a = [];

console.log('isEmpty(s): ' + isEmpty(s));
console.log('isEmpty(o): ' + isEmpty(o));
console.log('isEmpty(n): ' + isEmpty(n));
console.log('isEmpty(a): ' + isEmpty(a));
```

I'm tempted to modify the object line to check if the `length` property is defined, rather than restricting to `Array`s, but that's all I can think of offhand. Any other ideas on making this more general?

Answer (score 11):

One edge case you're missing is how to handle `null`. `isEmpty(null)` will  fail because `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(null)` will throw `TypeError: can't convert null to object`.

Also be aware that `isEmpty(NaN)` will return `false`, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Don't worry, this is a valid review! Even if your review is short or only points out flaws rather than solutions it is valuable to the OP and can be posted as an answer.